# Reading/writing CSV/tab delimited files in c#

Tags: c#, csv

I need to read from a CSV/Tab delimited file and write to such a file as well from .net.

The difficulty is that I don't know the structure of each file and need to write the cvs/tab file to a datatable, which the FileHelpers library doesn't seem to support.

I've already written it for Excel using OLEDB, but can't really see a way to write a tab file for this, so will go back to a library.

Can anyone help with suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I used this [CsvReader](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx), it is really great and well configurable. It behaves well with all kinds of escaping for strings and separators. The escaping in other quick and dirty implementations were poor, but this lib is really great at reading. With a few additional codelines you can also add a cache if you need to.

Writing is not supported but it rather trivial to implement yourself. Or inspire yourself from [this code](http://knab.ws/blog/index.php?/archives/3-CSV-file-parser-and-writer-in-C-Part-1.html).

Comment: Sorry.. it feels a little distant to me, but I guess my main consideration with writing csv files is delimiting the strings (it's been a while since I had to do csv files).

Comment: I added a link for CSV writing, you can replace some constant strings with your preferred delimiter, and it should be ok. Reading is far more complicated than writing...

Comment: But writing CSV files which contain arbitrary strings is non-trivial.  Remember escape sequences!

Comment: Why would you recommend this over the one that comes with .NET?

Answer (score 16):

.NET comes with a CSV/tab delminited file parser called the TextFieldParser class.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx

It supports the full RFC for CSV files and really good error reporting.

Comment: You have to love that general utility classes are in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to support specifying you own text wrapping character, it assumes this is a double quote and just allows you to turn on/off.

Comment: Could you provide a quick example? Links aren't sufficient answers. If it breaks this response is useless to any googler.

Answer (score 3):

Simple example with CsvHelper

```
using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath)
{
    var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(writer);
    csvWriter.Configuration.Delimiter = "\t";
    csvWriter.Configuration.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    csvWriter.WriteRecords(exportRecords); 
}
```

Comment: Property or indexer 'property' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple CSV reader implementations:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx

http://www.heikniemi.fi/jhlib/ (just one part of the library; includes a CSV writer too)

I doubt there is a standard way to convert CSV to DataTable or database 'automatically', you'll have to write code to do that. How to do that is a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

You'll create your datatable in code, and (presuming a header row) can create columns based on your first line in the file.  After that, it will simply be a matter of reading the file and creating new rows based on the data therein.

You could use something like this:

```
DataTable Tbl = new DataTable();
using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path))
{
  int count = 0;
  string headerRow = sr.Read();
  string[] headers = headerRow.split("\t") //Or ","
  foreach(string h in headers)
  {
    DataColumn dc = new DataColumn(h);
    Tbl.Columns.Add(dc);
    count++;
  }
  while(sr.Peek())
  {
    string data = sr.Read();
    string[] cells = data.Split("\t") 
    DataRow row = new DataRow();
    foreach(string c in cells)
    {
      row.Columns.Add(c);
    }
    Tbl.Rows.Add(row);
  }
}
```

The above code has not been compiled, so it may have some errors, but it should get you on the right track.

Comment: Your split code is wrong, as you may have the demliniator in a quoted string.

Comment: @Jonathan Allen: Yes, indeed you may.  It wasn't designed to be the full solution... just a pointer to a possible right track.

Comment: I get an error when using your code. The line 'while(sr.Peek())' is throwing an error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'bool'"

I am confused. I thought that integer value 0 evaluates to false in a Boolean, and all other integer values evaluate as true? Has C# syntax changed since this was written?

Answer (score 0):

You can read and write csv file.. 
This may be helpful for you.

**pass split char to this parameter "serparationChar"**

Example : -

```
    private DataTable dataTable = null;
    private bool IsHeader = true;
    private string headerLine = string.Empty;
    private List<string> AllLines = new List<string>();
    private StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    private char seprateChar = ',';


    public DataTable ReadCSV(string path, bool IsReadHeader, char serparationChar)
    {
        seprateChar = serparationChar;
        IsHeader = IsReadHeader;
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path,Encoding.Default))
        {
            while (!sr.EndOfStream)
            {
              AllLines.Add( sr.ReadLine());
            }
            createTemplate(AllLines);
        }

        return dataTable;
    }
    public void WriteCSV(string path,DataTable dtable,char serparationChar)
    {
        AllLines = new List<string>();
        seprateChar = serparationChar;
        List<string> StableHeadrs = new List<string>();
        int colCount = 0;
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path))
        {
            foreach (DataColumn col in dtable.Columns)
            {
                sb.Append(col.ColumnName);
                if(dataTable.Columns.Count-1 > colCount)
                sb.Append(seprateChar);
                colCount++;
            }
            AllLines.Add(sb.ToString());

            for (int i = 0; i < dtable.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                sb.Clear();
                for (int j = 0; j < dtable.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    sb.Append(Convert.ToString(dtable.Rows[i][j]));
                    if (dataTable.Columns.Count - 1 > j)
                    sb.Append(seprateChar);
                }
                AllLines.Add(sb.ToString());
            }

            foreach (string dataline in AllLines)
            {
                sw.WriteLine(dataline);
            }
        }


    }

    private DataTable createTemplate(List<string> lines)
    {

        List<string> headers = new List<string>();
        dataTable = new DataTable();
        if (lines.Count > 0)
        {
            string[] argHeaders = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < lines.Count; i++)
            {
                if (i > 0)
                {
                    DataRow newRow = dataTable.NewRow();
                    // others add to rows
                    string[] argLines = lines[i].Split(seprateChar);
                    for (int b = 0; b < argLines.Length; b++)
                    {
                        newRow[b] = argLines[b];
                    }
                    dataTable.Rows.Add(newRow);

                }
                else
                {
                    // header add to columns
                    argHeaders = lines[0].Split(seprateChar);
                    foreach (string c in argHeaders)
                    {
                        DataColumn column = new DataColumn(c, typeof(string));
                        dataTable.Columns.Add(column);
                    }
                }

            }

        }
        return dataTable;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found best solution

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/415732/Reading-and-Writing-CSV-Files-in-Csharp

Just I had to re-write

```
void ReadTest()
{
    // Read sample data from CSV file
    using (CsvFileReader reader = new CsvFileReader("ReadTest.csv"))
    {
        CsvRow row = new CsvRow();
        while (reader.ReadRow(row))
        {
            foreach (string s in row)
            {
                Console.Write(s);
                Console.Write(" ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();

            row = new CsvRow(); //this line added
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is another library [Cinchoo ETL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ChoETL/) - an open source one, for reading and writing CSV files.

Couple of ways you can read CSV files

```
Id, Name
1, Tom
2, Mark
```

This is how you can use this library to read it

```
using (var reader = new ChoCSVReader("emp.csv").WithFirstLineHeader())
{
   foreach (dynamic item in reader)
   {
      Console.WriteLine(item.Id);
      Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
   }
}
```

If you have POCO object defined to match up with CSV file like below

```
public class Employee
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

You can parse the same file using this POCO class as below

```
using (var reader = new ChoCSVReader<Employee>("emp.csv").WithFirstLineHeader())
{
   foreach (var item in reader)
   {
      Console.WriteLine(item.Id);
      Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
   }
}
```

Please check out articles at [CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1145337/Cinchoo-ETL-CS) on how to use it.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of this library