# how to read .tsv file using asp.net

Tags: c#

Hey all I have searched the web but couldn't find any solution to my problem. My problem is how to read a .tsv file using asp.net (C#). I am getting results for .csv only.

Is it the same like reading .csv file?

Comment: If your TSV is "tab separated values", you treat it just like a CSV or TXT.

Comment: Just google 'tab escape character'. Use this the same way you would a comma.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading/writing CSV/tab delimited files in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3134573/reading-writing-csv-tab-delimited-files-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [CsvHelper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsvHelper/)
- [FileHelpers](http://www.nuget.org/packages/FileHelpers/)

  This libraries can help you.

Answer (score 2):

[File handling](http://www.dotnetperls.com/file) Follow this guide, on dotnetperls.

```
line.Split(',');
```

you want

```
line.Split('\t');
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that [Fast CSV Reader](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader) is configurable enough to allow you to read tab-delimited files