# Write Tab Delimited File

Tags: c#, file, csv

I'm having trouble writing a Tab-delimited File and I've checked around here and have not gotten my answers yet.

So I've got a function that returns the string with the important pieces below (delimiter used and how I build each line):

```
var delimiter = @"\t";
sb.Append(string.Join(delimiter, itemContent));
sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
```

The string returned is like this:

```
H\t13\t170000000000001\t20150630
D\t1050\t10.0000\tY
D\t1050\t5.0000\tN
```

And then I write it to a file with this (content below is the string above):

```
var content = BuildFile(item);
var filePath = tempDirectory + fileName;

// Create the File
using (FileStream fs = File.Create(filePath))
{
    Byte[] info = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes(content);
    fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length);
}
```

However, the file output is this with no tabs (opened in notepad++):

```
H\t13\t170000000000005\t20150630
D\t1050\t20.0000\tN
D\t1050\t2.5000\tY
```

When it should be more like this (sample file provided):

```
H   100115980   300010000000003 20150625
D   430181  1   N
D   342130  2   N
D   459961  1   N
```

Could this be caused by the encoding I used? Appreciate any input you may have, thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading/writing CSV/tab delimited files in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3134573/reading-writing-csv-tab-delimited-files-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @OgnyanDimitrov not really, this is essentially a question about strings and C# syntax

Comment: You could also use [ControlChars.Tab](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.controlchars.tab.aspx) (`sb.Append(string.Join(ControlChars.Tab, itemContent));`), if you accept to add a reference to `Microsoft.VisualBasic`

Comment: use `Path.Combine(tempDirectory, fileName);`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Using `var delimiter = @"\t";`, the variable contains a literal `\` plus `t`. The @ syntax disables the backslash as "special". In this case you really want

```
var delimiter = "\t";
```

to have a tab character.

Answer (score 9):

There is a typo in your code. The `@` prefix means that the following string is a literal so @"\t" is a two-character string with the characters `\` and `t`

You should use "\t" without the prefix.

You should consider using a [StreamWriter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bh11f1k.aspx) instead of constructing the entire string in memory and writing the raw bytes though. StreamWriter uses UTF-8 by default and allows you to write formatted lines just as you would with Console.WriteLine:

```
var delimiter ="\t";

using(var writer=new StreamWriter(filePath))
{
    var line=string.Join(delimiter, itemContent);
    writer.WriteLine(line);
}
```