# Automatic text formatting

Tags: java, c#, text, scripting, formatting

I have a bunch of logs within text files that currently look like garbage. For example:

```
Name;BlahBlah;2015-08-11T23:34:19.7532939Z;Somethingsomething;abcdef;;something2;1.344.3.5.55;;;;sdfsdf;"ABCDEF";
```

My task is to make this more readable. So, my first instinct is to separate the info by the delimiters. In this case, I think ; is the delimiter. How would I go about doing this? Is there some tool/program out there that already does this? I could replace each delimiter by a newline and store that edited log into a new text file.

Comment: For C#, check this question out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3134573/reading-writing-csv-tab-delimited-files-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you've given us enough to work with yet. Why are java and C# tagged on this question, for one? The semicolons-to-newlines problem is easy to answer, though, so I'll answer it.

I've been working with [sed](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) all day, so I'm going to suggest sed. If you're working on a Unix or Linux machine, or have some sort of *nix-like environment like Cygwin, you probably have access to sed, and it'll handle the problem nicely.

For example, if the line you gave is in a file named test.txt, the following command will replace all of the semicolons in the log file with newlines and print it out to console:

```sh
cat test.txt | sed "s/;/\n/g"
```

That solves the semicolon problem, assuming the data part of your logs doesn't have any semicolons in it. You could extend this with a script to run sed on everything in a directory.

Alternatives to sed include awk, or Perl, which is more portable. There's also the find/replace all option in most text editors.