# How to export a row in a DataGridView to a txt file

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, export

As I can select a row in a DataGridView and export it to a .txt file that has the name of a column of DataGridView

At the moment I have a button to export all data to a .txt gridview here is the code

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   
        if (!Directory.Exists(@"D:\Carpeta"))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(@"D:\Carpeta");
        }

        TextWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"D:\Carpeta\Archivo.txt");
        int rowcount = TablaDatos.Rows.Count;
        for(int i = 0; i < rowcount -1; i++)
        {
            sw.WriteLine(TablaDatos.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString()+"\t"
                         +TablaDatos.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString()+"\t"
                          +TablaDatos.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString()+"\t"
                           +TablaDatos.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString()+"\t");
        }
        sw.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Datos Exportados correctamente");    
    }
```

I need to export row by row creating a txt for each row and not the entire DataGridView

[image]

Comment: Does it have to be Tab delimited in the text file ? or can it be Json format ?

Comment: Take a look at some SO sample how to read [write CSV data](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23950516/444149)

Answer (score 0):

There you go.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (!Directory.Exists(@"D:\Carpeta"))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(@"D:\Carpeta");

    for (int i = 0; i < TablaDatos.RowCount; ++i) {
        var line = string.Join("\t", TablaDatos.Rows[i].Cells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>());
        File.WriteAllText(@"D:\Carpeta\" + $"Archivo-row-{i}.csv", line);
    }

    MessageBox.Show("Datos Exportados correctamente");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use either of these options:

**Option 1**

Set the `MultiSelect` property of grid to `false` and then select desired row, then you can use [`DataGridView.GetClipboardContent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.getclipboardcontent(v=vs.110).aspx). This method retrieves the formatted values that represent the contents of the selected cells for copying to the Clipboard. The result is tab-delimited:

```
grid.MultiSelect = false;
grid.Rows[i].Selected = true;
grid.ClipboardCopyMode = DataGridViewClipboardCopyMode.EnableWithoutHeaderText;
var text = grid.GetClipboardContent().GetText();
```

**Option 2**

you can get text representation for the row at index `i` by joining formatted value of each cells. The result could be delimited by any character that you need:

```
var text = string.Join("\t", grid.Rows[i].Cells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>()
                                 .Where(x=> x.Visible).Select(x=> x.FormattedValue));
```

**To save text to a file**

You can use [`File.WriteAllText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealltext(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filePath, text);
```